# Are the actions or events in Ghostbusters II (1989) ever referenced in Ghostbusters: Afterlife (2021)?

Tags: ghostbusters

The film *Ghostbusters: Afterlife* (2021) contains many references to events shown in the original *Ghostbusters* (1984), which are historical events within the time line of the movie. However, I realised after watching it that it didn't make much reference to the events of *Ghostbusters II* (1989), even though some of those would also be quite widely known. (I'm thinking of the statue of Liberty scene in particular.)

It makes sense that *Ghostbusters: Afterlife* pays more attention to the original *Ghostbusters*, both because *Ghostbusters* was the bigger commercial success and because *Ghostbusters: Afterlife* builds directly on plot elements from *Ghostbusters*. However I'm wondering if there are also references to *Ghostbusters II* anywhere in the film.

TL;DR: are there any specific references to *Ghostbusters II* in *Ghostbusters: Afterlife*, and if so, what are they?

Comment: Ghostbusters II was the bigger commercial success, at least at the Box Office on its first release. GB1 has pulled it back on re-releases though.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are some small references, but they also wanted to stick (mainly) with the iconic images from the *original* Ghostbusters film, noting that this is a Gozer film, not a Vigo film.

> **JR:** *And Ghostbusters II is canon*.
>
> **People keep wondering if it is or not.**
>
> **JR:** *No, Ghostbusters II, definitely canon. There are references to
> Ghostbusters II in Afterlife. We meet Ray working at [Ray’s Occult](https://ghostbusters.fandom.com/wiki/Ray%27s_Occult_Books#Ghostbusters:_Afterlife). The
> toaster from Ghostbusters II is in the kitchen in the farmhouse.
> There’s actually lots of lost of Ghostbusters II details but nobody
> knows Ghostbusters II outside of Vigo the Carpathian and the
> Ghostbusters II logo. So there’s this assumption that it is not canon
> but it is definitely canon.*
>
> **The second plot question, when we see the pictures of young Carrie
> Coon they are from the late 1980s. So Egon has a kid in Ghostbusters
> II?**
>
> **JR:** *Oh, yeah.*
>
> **Okay. We just don’t know that at the time when we’re watching
> Ghostbusters II.**
>
> **JR:** *Correct.*
>
> <sub><sup>[In Which We Talk To Jason Reitman About Almost Everything Except ‘Ghostbusters: Afterlife’](https://uproxx.com/movies/jason-reitman-ghostbusters-afterlife-interview/)</sup></sub>

They seem to have made some effort to give GB2 fans some red meat by adding a few of the film's prop items to a '*[continuity cavalcade](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ContinuityCavalcade)*' in the barn where the Ecto-1 is being stored, and dotted around the house as we pan around rooms.

The **dancing toaster** seen in the kitchen [note, not the original prop, but made by the same company].

[image]

**The Ecto-1a numberplate** also makes a brief appearance in the barn [cut from the film, but shown on the DVD].

[image]

As does **the box that the ooze came out of** [cut from the film, but shown on the DVD].

and the [**Giga Meter**](https://ghostbusters.fandom.com/wiki/Giga_meter).

[image]

The ["**we're back" lightboard**](https://ghostbusters.fandom.com/wiki/Ecto-1a?file=GB2film1999chapter12sc079.png) from the side of the Ecto-1a.

[image]

And of course the style of [**ribbon connectors**](https://www.gbfans.com/equipment/proton-pack/ribbon-cable/) on the packs used by Ray, et al *clearly* indicates that they're from the GB2 era.

[image]